# Obtener las dimensiones de una imagen a traves de una url en swift

Tags: swift, alamofireimage

Como puedo obtener las dimensiones de una imagen que esta en una url desde `swift`??

de momento tengo este código para mostrar la imagen:

```
imagenPrincipal.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
let URL = NSURL(string: oferta!.imagen)!
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder")!
imagenPrincipal.sd_setImageWithURL(URL, placeholderImage: placeholderImage, completed: nil)
```

Utilizo `AlamofireImage` para mostrar la imagen

Necesito modificar el tamaño de la imagen en funcion del ancho de la pantalla y el tamaño de la imagen manteniendo el `aspect ratio`

Gracias

Comment: Para cambiar el tamaño de una imagen, hay una pregunta en ingles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966885/ios-swift-resize-image-to-200x200pt-px a ver si te sirve

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es redimensionar el tamaño de la imagen y la altura segun la grandaria de la pantalla , utiliza el equal height y el equal width **imagen equal width to view** como contraints y maneja la proporción que le quieres dar con la propiedad multiplier de la constraint , de esta manera la imagen crecerá ese tanto por ciento que le indicas en el multiplier en función del tamaño de la view.